# schema privilege 'createin' cannot be revoked

Tags: db2

I need to revoke CREATEIN privilege for PUBLIC in a schema named THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX, I connected to the database and typed the following commands

this one to verify PUBLIC has createin permissions in the schema

```
db2 "select schemaname,CREATEINAUTH from SYSCAT.SCHEMAAUTH where GRANTEE= 'PUBLIC'"

SCHEMANAME                                              CREATEINAUTH                                                   
THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX                                   Y

db2 revoke CREATEIN ON SCHEMA 'THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX' FROM PUBLIC
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0108N  The name "COM" has the wrong number of qualifiers.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

i also tried with "" but got the same result

```
db2 "revoke CREATEIN ON SCHEMA THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX FROM PUBLIC"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0108N  The name "COM" has the wrong number of qualifiers.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db2 "revoke CREATEIN ON SCHEMA \"THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX\" FROM PUBLIC"
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is any special character in db2 command that is not accepted by OS command line, you may keep the command in file with some delimiter and run the file from OS command line.

For eg. create a file with name say revoke.sql and keep following statement in it:

revoke CREATEIN ON SCHEMA THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX FROM PUBLIC;

Then you can execute this file as follows:
db2 -tvf revoke.sql

Comment: The problem is not with shell special characters. You may see, that the whole statement is inside the double quotes, but it still fails. The problem is, that such a schema identifier must be wrapped into double quotes in an sql statement to be properly interpreted. This is why your sql statement fails as well, and you must use the following one: `revoke CREATEIN ON SCHEMA "THOMAS.XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX" FROM PUBLIC`